# Concern about memory when choosing between notification vs callback closure for network calls?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, nsnotificationcenter

Many posts seem to advise against notifications when trying to synchronize functions, but there are also other posts which caution against closure callbacks because of the potential to inadvertently retain objects and cause memory issues.

Assume inside a custom view controller is a function, `foo`, that uses the `Bar` class to get data from the server.

```
class CustomViewController : UIViewController {

    function foo() {
       // Do other stuff
       // Use Bar to get data from server
       Bar.getServerData()
     }

}
```

**Option 1:** Define `getServerData` to accept a callback. Define the callback as a closure inside `CustomViewController`.

**Option 2:** Use `NSNotifications` instead of a callback. Inside of `getServerData`, post a `NSNotification` when the server returns data, and ensure `CustomViewController` is registered for the notification.

Option 1 seems desirable for all the reasons people caution against `NSNotification` (e.g., compiler checks, traceability), but doesn't using a callback create a potential issue where `CustomViewController` is unnecessarily retained and therefore potentially creating memory issues?

If so, is the right way to mitigate the risk by using a callback, but not using a closure? In other words, define a function inside `CustomViewController` with a signature matching the `getServerData` callback, and pass the pointer to this function to `getServerData`?

Comment: IMHO, both are valid approaches. Option 1 is far more concise, comprehensible and easy to get correct. Thus, Option 1 is preferred. It seems though, you are misguided by some other answers:  memory management and synchronisation are orthogonal concepts and have their own roots of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm always going with **Option 1** you just need to remember of using `[weak self]` or whatever you need to 'weakify' in order to avoid memory problems.

Real world example:

```
filterRepository.getFiltersForType(filterType) { [weak self] (categories)  in
    guard let strongSelf = self, categories = categories else { return }
    strongSelf.dataSource           = categories
    strongSelf.filteredDataSource   = strongSelf.dataSource
    strongSelf.tableView?.reloadData()
}
```

So in this example you can see that I pass reference to `self` to the completion closure, but as `weak` reference. Then I'm checking if the object still exists - if it wasn't released already, using `guard` statement and unwrapping `weak` value.

Definition of network call with completion closure:

```
class func getFiltersForType(type: FilterType, callback: ([FilterCategory]?) -> ()) {
    connection.getFiltersCategories(type.id).response { (json, error) in
        if let data = json {
            callback(data.arrayValue.map { FilterCategory(attributes: $0) } )
        } else {
            callback(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The need for `weak self` is often overstated.  You need to have a circular reference to generate a retain cycle and therefore a memory leak.  In your example the closure captures `self` but the `FilterRepository` does not capture the closure into a strong property, so as soon as `getFiltersForType` invokes the closure, it's hold on the closure is released.  This means that the closure is released and the closures hold on the calling object (`self`) is released, so everything cleans up nicely

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for the comment, I made mistake copying the code, `filterRepository` is a property in my data source object, hence `weak`

Comment: It doesn't matter about `filterRepository` - you only have the potential for a leak if you do something like `self.closureProperty = callback` in `getFiltersForType`

Comment: The use of `[weak self]` vs implicit `strong self` depends on your goals, and it's not _generally_ wrong respectively correct. That is, there are two valid use cases where you sometimes want either `weak` and other times you want `strong`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm standing for closures in that case. To avoid unnecessary retains you just need to ensure closure has proper [capture list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) defined.